# How to set x-axis ticks to month ends?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, axis-labels

I am trying to set x-axis ticks to month ends in ggplot2. Currently the plot generated has ticks that correspond to the first of the month. The code I am using to generate the scale is

```
p + scale_x_date(limits = c(as.Date("2006-12-31"), as.Date("2014-09-30")), date_breaks = "6 months", date_labels = "%Y-%m-%d")
```

I would have thought that since my limits are month ends it ticks would also be month ends. Furthermore, my data starts on 2007-01-02 so the first tick is 2007-02-01. I would like to set the ticks in line with quarter ends.

Comment: Please add a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) as shown in the link.  This will include a minimal dataset and your plotting code that shows the problem you are having.

Answer (score 2):

One way to get the exact axis breaks you want is to specify them explicitly by supplying a vector of dates to the `breaks` argument in `scale_x_date`. You haven't provided a reproducible example, so I've plotted some fake data. In the code below, I've specified breaks at the end of each quarter. I needed to subtract one day from each of the 30-day months, so that the break would be on the last day of the quarter, rather than on the first day of the next quarter.

```
# Fake data
dat = data.frame(date=seq(as.Date("2006-12-31"), as.Date("2014-09-30"), by="1 day"))
set.seed(495)
dat$value = cumsum(rnorm(nrow(dat)))

ggplot(dat, aes(date, value)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  scale_x_date(limits = c(as.Date("2006-12-31"), as.Date("2014-09-30")), 
               breaks = seq(as.Date("2006-03-31"), as.Date("2014-12-31"), "quarter") - c(0,1,1,0),
               date_labels = "%Y-%m-%d", expand=c(0,30)) +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-90, vjust=0.5))
```

[image]